# How to fill all column in SAP GUI SCRIPT by IF / IFEND

Tags: sap-gui, rpa

As i was trying to RPA my SAP, I encountered a problem.
[image]
by using SAP script recoding, i was able to fill these column one by one by this script code.
under is my script code.

```
    `If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").currentCellColumn = "FLIEF"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").pressF4
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/lbl[1,3]").caretPosition = 6
session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell")
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").modifyCell 1,"FLIEF","1190361578"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 1
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").triggerModified
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").modifyCell 2,"FLIEF","1190361578"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").triggerModified
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").modifyCell 3,"FLIEF","1190361578"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").currentCellRow = 3
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_ALV/shellcont/shell").triggerModified`
```

and so on.

However my rows are over atleast 100.

So what i want is it needs to repeat until it reaches the end of the row.

like this.
[image]
The repeated data is same.
Please teach me if there is a easier way.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying you do not know how to build a loop? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/cbe735w2(v=vs.84)

Comment: The screenshot shows a [GuiGridView object](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows?locale=en-US&q=GuiGridView). It's already answered.

Comment: Yes i do not know how to bulid a loop, even i do not know what language this sap gui uses.

Comment: what i want is it need to be looped to fill the blank until it reaches to end of the row, or fill the blank all at once. I tried [modifyCell 1,"FLIEF","1190361578"] into [modifyCellColumn ,"FLIEF","1190361578"] but it does not work